# Cypress tests not running

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress, teardown

[image]

whenever I am trying to run cypress tests I am getting this error.
I have cloned spectrum repo and this is my first time I am trying to run cypress tests

Comment: How does the test look like?

Answer (score 0):

The test appears to have timed out after waiting for a full minute.
Try checking the response for error, along with the lines of

```
cy.exec('npm run build').then((result) => {
  console.log("code---->", result.code);
  console.log("stdout---->", result.stdout);
  console.log("error---->", result.stderr);
})
```

Replace 'npm run build' with your code.

Also, what exactly are you trying to do there, in the before block?